# Scrapy. I can't make a request within my parse method to scrape another page and I can't run the scraper from a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, spyder

I am trying to crawl videos from alibaba, I am trying to make it with a script, and maybe make a simple app with tkinter later.

Two problems:
1-I am getting this error.

```
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

it could run the first time, but then I can't rerun it to test changes, if it works like this I may not be able to run it with tkinter later.

Here is the spider, which I am sure it works as currently required (it is unfinished, I haven't got to the videos download yet, help on that maybe?), because I have tested it individually on scrapy shell.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import json
class AlibabaCrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibaba_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    page=1
    start_urls = ['https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/packaging-machine_cid100009422?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.pagination.2.60817b5a5GeA75' +'&page='+str(page)]

    def parse(self, response):

        parser = scrapy.Selector(response)
        products = parser.xpath("//div[@class='item-main']")
        for product in products:
            videoWaterMarkPath=".//div[@class='item-img-inner']/a/div[@class='icon-wrap']/div[@class='watermark has-video']/i"
            if (len(product.xpath(videoWaterMarkPath))>0):
                link=".//div[@class='item-img-inner']/a/@href"
                #print("https:"+product.xpath(link).extract()[0])
                scrapy.Request("https:"+product.xpath(link).extract()[0],callback=self.parseItem)

    def parseItem(self,response):
        print(response.url)
        script= (response.xpath("//script[@type='application/ld+json']/text()").extract()[0])
        jsonData=json.loads(script)
        videoLinks=[]
        if(len(jsonData) >1):
            for data in jsonData:
                if data['@type']=='VideoObject':
                    videoLinks.append(data['contentUrl'])
                print (videoLinks)
        print(videoLinks)

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(AlibabaCrawlerSpider)
process.start()
```

Which gets us to the second problem, after testing the spider on the with `scrapy crawl`, it stops working at `parse` and it doesn't seem to go into `parseItem`, am I doing something wrong in `scrapy.Request`?

Comment: I've not tested your code, but should you not be 'yielding' your Request objects? Have you done the [tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)?

Comment: well I haven't got the results I want to yield yet, I have been stuck on that for a long time

Comment: I’m suggesting you try to yield your `scrapy.Request`. Have you tried that?